# Generating Objective-c client side code for consuming Rest Services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rest, code-generation

I am working on building an iPhone application that uses an external server to store most of the data. The server exposes all the required services using a REST API.

Ideally I would like to generate the client side code in objective-c that can consume these services. Preferably these should return objects that I can easily use instead of having to parse the return XML.

What options am I looking at ? I have researched quiet a bit on this and the closest to code generation I have seen is [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) . Since I also own the backend services I could make them SOAP based services, but I really prefer not to do that since I will later on use the same set of services to build a Web UI ( for eg).  Other option I have is to go with [RestKit](http://restkit.org/).

Any guidance on this is much appreciated. I am pretty sure this is a use case lots of people have faced and I just am not able to find the right resources or am not looking at the right places.

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestKit is a great framework. You're still going to have to write code, but it will make the process of moving data between Cocoa models and RESTful/JSON web services elegantly straightforward. I recommend running through the examples to get your head around their way of doing things.

Comment: RestKit was my first choice given all the choices I have. It is good to know that others too think this is the one framework to use REST based iPhone apps.

Comment: it would be great if you could put your thoughts on my question on  [how to use RestKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661842/best-way-to-use-restkit-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with using `ResKit`, which allows not only to ease `REST` services consuming, but also mapping to `CoreData` and others if I remember well.

And about `CoreData` I would suggest using [Mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) that intended to generate CoreData code, but it is also allowing  more, since it can basically be used as a template based code generator from `CoreData` Models...

A good match to your question could be some Mo' templates filling the gap between both.